# Why gradle replaces jar version from gradle file

Tags: gradle

In my gradle file, the instruction is to use version 0.9.12:

```
compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.12'
```

However, gradle insist of changing and downloading version 0.10:
[image]

When I run the command to see all dependencies, I can see that:
[image]

Where exactly can I find the definition to use version 0.10 instead of 0.9.12? Where is it configured?

Thanks

Expecting to use version 0.9.12 as appears in gradle.build file, however, gradle download version 0.10

Comment: Something in your dependency graph depends on the later version. Also in the future [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: That is exactly my question, in which configuration I can see that dependency on later version?